# Firebase angularfire child.$asObject give properties undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've got this code:

**factory**

```
app.factory('Items', function($firebase,FIREBASE_URL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var items = $firebase(ref.child('items')).$asArray();
    var Item = {
        all: function () {
          return items;
        },
        create: function (item) {
          return items.$add(item);
        },
        get: function (itemId) {
          return $firebase(ref.child('items').child(itemId)).$asObject();
        },
        update: function (itemId, item) {
          return $firebase(ref.child('items').child(itemId)).update(item);
        },
        delete: function (item) {
          return items.$remove(item);
        }
    };
    return Item;
});
```

**route**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider      
        .state('items_update', {
            url: '/items/update/:id',
            templateUrl: 'views/items/form.html',
            controller:'ItemsUpdateController',
            resolve:{
                item:function(Items,$stateParams){
                    return Items.get($stateParams.id);
                }
            }
        })
});
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('ItemsUpdateController', function ($scope, item, $state) {
    $scope.item = item;
    console.log($scope.item.url);
    $scope.add = function() {
        Items.update($scope.item).then(function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        });
    }
});
```

why console.log($scope.item.url); give me undefined ?

but in the view I've got all the data

**html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form" data-ng-submit="add()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="title" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'items.form.title' | translate }}" data-ng-model="item.title" required="required" data-ng-minlength="3" data-ng-maxlength="25" user-feedback />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="ingredients" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'items.form.ingredients' | translate }}" data-ng-model="item.ingredients" required="required" ng-pattern="/^\w(\s*,?\s*\w)*$/" user-feedback />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="price" tabindex="3" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'items.form.price' | translate }}" data-ng-model="item.price" required="required" data-smart-float user-feedback />  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" tabindex="4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" item="item" data-uploader>{{ 'items.form.upload' | translate }}</button>
        <input type="text" name="url" style="display:none;" required="required" data-ng-model="item.url" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-no-required clearfix">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="submit" tabindex="5" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid">{{ 'items.form.submit' | translate }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ENDS UP**

as in the @Frank van Puffelen comment
I worked it out with:

```
app.controller('ItemsUpdateController', function($scope, item, $state) {
    item.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        $scope.item = data;  
        console.log($scope.item.url);
    });
    $scope.add = function() {
        Items.update($scope.item).then(function() {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is because by the time your `console.log($scope.item.url);` runs, the data hasn't been loaded from Firebase yet. Angular listens for a notification from Firebase/AngularFire to know when the data has loaded and then updates the view. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395912/angularfire-why-cant-i-loop-over-array-returned-by-asarray/26403301#26403301 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268446/trying-to-get-child-records-from-firebase/26277382#26277382.

Comment: +1 thanks a ton :) usually the promise is done by resolve in ui-router so angularfire doesn't use promise like restangular ?

Comment: AngularFire most definitely uses promises. They just resolve seem to later than you may be used to, likely because the data has to come down from the Firebase server. If you want to wait for the AngularFire promise, do `$scope.item.$loaded().then(function(item) { console.log(item.url); })`. In general: don't waste time trying to make asynchronous code synchronous, work with its async nature and put your functionality behind promises/inside callbacks.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen mmm look at the code there is the way when user can click to update a not loaded item so do think is a good idea to put the add function inside $loaded block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because by the time your `console.log($scope.item.url);` runs, the data hasn't been loaded from Firebase yet. Angular listens for a notification from Firebase/AngularFire to know when the data has loaded and then updates the view.

Also see [angularfire - why can't I loop over array returned by $asArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395912/angularfire-why-cant-i-loop-over-array-returned-by-asarray/26403301#26403301) and [Trying to get child records from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268446/trying-to-get-child-records-from-firebase/26277382#26277382).