# Firebase angularfire how to update an item

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I don't find the way to update an item
(You can find all the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604472/firebase-angularfire-child-asobject-give-properties-undefined))
I tried with this code

```
app.factory('Items', function($firebase,FIREBASE_URL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var items = $firebase(ref.child('items')).$asArray();
    var Item = {
        all: function () {
          return items;
        },
        create: function (item) {
          return items.$add(item);
        },
        get: function (itemId) {
          return $firebase(ref.child('items').child(itemId)).$asObject();
        },
        update: function (itemId, item) {
          return $firebase(ref.child('items').child(itemId)).update(item);
        },
        delete: function (item) {
          return items.$remove(item);
        }
    };
    return Item;
});
```

but it doesn't work.
Can you help me, please ?

I've tried after the comment of Frank van Puffelen
to

```
update: function (item) {
    return items.$save(item);
}
```

but it doesn't work and get me

*Object { status=2, value="Invalid record; could d...ts key: [object Object]"}*

You can see a workish example at :

https://lalista.firebaseapp.com

Answer (score 4):

If you have an explicit `update` function, you're not using Angular's/AngularFire's two-way/three-way data binding. In that case you might as well bypass AngularFire for the update and call Firebase's JavaScript API directly:

```
 update: function (itemId, item) {
     return ref.child('items').child(itemId).set(item);
 }
```

Note that I call [`set`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html) instead of [`update`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html), because it looks like you're trying to replace any existing data Firebase might be storing for the item.

Firebase's JavaScript API and AngularFire play nicely together here, so you don't have to worry about the data getting out of sync.

Comment: thanks again :) for the point but it's my fault I mixed up plain firebase with angularfire so what's the way to do update with angularfire ?

Comment: I tried to use like your reply but I've got Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($$conf). Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Comment: That sounds like you did `update('$$conf')` or something like that. Can you share the code snippet you used?

Comment: You can see the workish example https://lalista.firebaseapp.com now I've  set items.$save(item) but you've got all the code.

Comment: Replace this `console.log(Items.update(item.$id,item));` with `Items.child(item.$id).update(item);`. Please use the documentation : https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html

Comment: Sorry but I miss the point Items doesn't have a child method and the signature of Items.update is Items.update(itemId,item)

Comment: Then you're still using AngularFire, where the whole point of my answer was to bypass AngularFire and simply use Firebase's regular JavaScript API.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think what Whisher was saying is that any data that comes by way of AngularFire, will inherently contain keys that regular ole Firebase won't accept ($conf, $id etc), metadata on the object. That is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody coming to this question using the new AngularFire APIs `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject`, the methods are:

[`$firebaseArray.$save(recordOrIndex)`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex)

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
    list[2].foo = "bar";
list.$save(2).then(function(ref) {
  ref.key() === list[2].$id; // true
});
```

[`$firebaseObject.$save()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-save)

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.foo = "bar";
obj.$save().then(function(ref) {
  ref.key() === obj.$id; // true
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
});
```