# AngularFire get count of child data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to count the total data in a users profile in my firebase. Therefore I first get the profile as object:

```
var profile = $firebase(ref.child('profile').child(userId)).$asObject();
```

Now If I console.log this var there is this object:

[image]

I found some solutions to count the object with

```
console.log(Object.keys(profile));
```

But this gives me only the count 3. always:

[image]

Anyone got a solution how I can get the count of the data stored? 
There should be age, gender, place, realname, username = 5

Comment: Try with profile.$loaded.then(function(data) {console.log(data);});

Comment: you rock. thanks. Post this as an answer and explain a little so i can accept it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase angularfire child.$asObject give properties undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604472/firebase-angularfire-child-asobject-give-properties-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
profile.$loaded.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Take a look at the first comment in this 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604472/firebase-angularfire-child-asobject-give-properties-undefined)